# Adding a jbutton in a jmenu that executes a different class

Tags: java, swing, class, jbutton, jmenu

Not sure if what I am asking makes sense. But I have a class that has a jmenu, along with a jframe with a graph init. I would like to know if it is possible to add a jbutton as jmenu item, so that when it is clicked, it will run a different class . Thanks in advance

Comment: `I would like to know if it is possible to add a jbutton as jmenu item,` - why would you use a JButton? JMenu's are designed to use a JMenuItem. `it will run a different class` - you just add an ActionListener to the menu item to do whatever you want, so yes you can create and run a different class.

Comment: But still you could go and add some render changes and let know your JMenu how to render a JButton.